# New Session created unexpectedly. Also a new session file created on next page

Tags: php, session

Here is my login.php code snippet:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db_connection.php';

if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $match_flag = false;
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];


    //$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

    $query_select = "SELECT admin_username, admin_password FROM users_admin";
    $query_result = $conn->query($query_select);
    if($query_result){
        foreach($query_result as $rows){
            if(($rows['admin_username'] == $username)&&($rows['admin_password'] == $password)){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                echo "<br> Session ID -> ".SID;
                $match_flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if($match_flag){

        echo "1";
    }else{
        echo "0";
    }
    exit();
}
?>
```

And here is my dashboard.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();

echo "Session is -> ".$_SESSION['username'];
echo "<br> Session ID -> ".SID;
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=http://www.example/login.php">';
    exit();
}
?>
```

After running login.php the session value is set and I get session ID and when I see session file, I found with fine content. But when the dashboard.php runs, I get another but different session id there with an empty session file. It means a new session is being created on running dashboard.php but this is totally unexpectedly. I have searched a lot but did not get satisfy-able answer. Please guide my why session is again started on a new page?

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: @RyanVincent yes all pages are in http. no any https

Answer (score 1):

This is just an educated guess but maybe there is a problem with the way how you provide your session name and session ID. It is crucial that both of your scripts are aware of the same session ID.

There are several ways to do so.
Nowadays most PHP installations are configured to use cookies and only cookies. A few PHP versions ago session parameters were transferred through URL parameters.
 The way PHP handles these is configured in your php.ini.
You might find the section on session configuration in the PHP Manual helpful: http://php.net/manual/session.configuration.php
Make sure to check out the `session.use_cookies` and `session.use_trans_sid` directives. For security reasons I suggest you set everything to the default values. You may look into your current configuration through `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`.

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I have checked configuration through <?php phpinfo(); ?>

My `session.use_cookies` is set to Off (Local and Master both) and `session.use_trans_sid` is set to 0 (Local and Master both)

I don't know much about these configuration values. Are they ok?

Comment: Try setting `session.use_cookies` to `1` (it should be the default setting) in your php.ini file. Then try running your script again and let me know if that worked for you.